# Check if a list of words is in a string (Small Chatbot)

Tags: javascript, jquery, chatbot

With the aim of building a small chabot in JS, I need to check if one of the word I put on a list is in a string, like this :

> var helloWords = ["hello", "salut", "hi", "yo", "hey"];
>
> var HowWords = ["how are you", "what's up", "how is it going", "how do you do"];
>
> If "one of the words from helloWords is in the string"
>
> -> Reply something
>
> If "one of the words from howWords is in the string"
>
> -> Reply something else

I'm currently using the method below but it's not practical at all and i'm getting lost in a long if/else program...

> var hello = /\bhello\b|\bhi\b|\byo\b|\bsalut\b/gi.test(commands);
>
> if (hello == true} ....

Do you know if there's a cleaner and more efficient method to build something like this ? Maybe in an other langage ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains).

To match the whole string:

```
var helloWords = ["hello", "salut", "hi", "yo", "hey"];

var HowWords = ["how are you", "what's up", "how is it going", "how do you do"];

if (helloWords.includes(yourString.toLowerCase())) {
    // Reply something
}
if (HowWords.includes(yourString.toLowerCase())) {

    // Reply something else
}
```

To match partial string, you'll need to do something like this using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var helloWords = ["hello", "salut", "hi", "yo", "hey"];

var HowWords = ["how are you", "what's up", "how is it going", "how do you do"];

if (helloWords.some( i => yourString.toLowerCase().includes(i) )) {
    // Reply something
}
if (HowWords.some( i => yourString.toLowerCase().includes(i) )) {
    // Reply something else
}
```

Comment: I would add `toLowerCase` to yourString, just to make it work more easily

Comment: It's working when the string contain only the word.
Like : "Hello" is working
"Hello world" is not working
Do you know why ?

Comment: @Enhancer I updated the answer, I've added a way to filter partial string

Comment: @Ele You're right, `filter` was not the best option. I changed to `some`

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend you [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for a wider browser compatibility:**

```
var helloWords = ["hello", "salut", "hi", "yo", "hey"];
var HowWords = ["how are you", "what's up", "how is it going", "how do you do"];

if (helloWords.indexOf(yourString.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
// Logic
}
if (HowWords.indexOf(yourString.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
// Logic
}
```

> Hello, thank you for the help. But I've got a problem, it's working only when there's only the word (exemple) "hello" but if the string is "hello you" it's not working.

An alternative is using the function `some`:

```js
var helloWords = ["hello", "salut", "hi", "yo", "hey"];
var HowWords = ["how are you", "what's up", "how is it going", "how do you do"];

var input = 'hello you',
    samples = input.split(/\s+/g); // split the entered value by spaces.
if (helloWords.some((h) => samples.includes(h.trim().toLowerCase()))) {
  console.log('Logic for helloWords');
}

// This condition returns false because neither 'hello' nor 'you' is within
// the array HowWords.
if (HowWords.some((h) => samples.includes(h.trim().toLowerCase()))) {
  console.log('Logic for HowWords');
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help. But I've got a problem, it's working only when there's only the word (exemple) "hello" but if the string is "hello you" it's not working

I'm getting the string with the following code, maybe the .val is the problem :

var commands2 = $(".letsTypeIt").val();

Comment: @Enhancer see the updated answer, that approach doesn't create a new array, just validate is one of the words is within the arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the help and for your time :)